# Cannot select individual words with fixed layout .epub documents

Tags: uiwebview, epub, textselection

I have a reader app that loads `.epub` files and usually I have no problem with selection at all, lately I have integrated fixed layout `.epub` files but I'm facing a problem: when I have a box containing one line the selection works fine, but when the box contains several lines, meaning several `<p></p>`, I cannot select a single word from the box. On selection the whole box gets selected as shown in the screenshot. When I try the same `.epub` file on iBooks, the selection works fine on all text. Any idea how I can fix the issue?

Here is the code for loading the file on `UiWebView`.

```
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:itemPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if (!contents) {
    contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:itemPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
}
[readingWebView loadHTMLString:contents baseURL:baseURL];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got the answer.

When using this function:

```
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", font];
```

to set the font size some restrictions are set on the web view, one of them is related to the selection with fixed layout epubs.

I used instead:

```
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize= '%d%%'", font];
```